# Next.js ^13.4 Data Cache does not appear to be caching duplicate requests

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am using nextjs and its new app directory layout, and have been referencing [this link](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#caching-data) in regards to caching and strategy.

I have a dynamic SSG page that builds thousands of instances of that page. Each page makes two api calls, one for common data that instances share (`/api/categories`) and one that makes a unique call for that page instance. Below is what the total requests look like:

```
const [categories, pageData] = await Promise.all([
    await getAllCategories(), --> fetch('/api/categories')
    await getPageData(slug),  --> fetch('/api/pageData/${slug}')
  ]);
```

These are hitting an external api I control, and I am logging each request made. Since `getAllCategories()` is the same request across all these pages, at build time I would expect the first request to be made since it is a cache miss, and then all subsequent requests to be served in memory (docs say they are memoized) and not actually hit my api again until I build again or invalidate the cache.

This is not what I am seeing, I am still seeing each duplicate request hit my server. I am running the latest version of nextjs (`13.4.4`) and have even tried adding the fetch option `{ cache: 'force-cache' }`, but am still not seeing the requests being cached.

Am I misunderstanding how caching works with the nextjs Data cache, or is my understanding correct and there is some other side effect causing the cache to not act as desired?

I have been logging all requests made to my server, and am still seeing the same duplicate requests being made to my server. I have thousands of pages that are being compiled at build time, and this is causing my builds to be very slow.